# facebook request reading and user_id geting issue

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi im sending my request like this

```
 <?php 
         $app_id = "127736900693315";

         $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/greetingz";

         $message = "Dynamic_msg";
         $data_s="Dynamic_data";


         $requests_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" 
                . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
                . "&message=" . $message."&data=".$data_s;

         if (empty($_REQUEST["request_ids"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url . "'</script>");


         } else {

         }
?>
```

this request is going ok but when receiver click on notification im fetching through request_ids code is below

```
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {

    $config = array(
        'appId' => '343704039016593',
        'secret' => '56e711bf93d4e46426aa662c8be8d5ef',
        'cookie' => true,

    );
       $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        echo  $user_id= $facebook->getUser(); //** 0 printing**
        $app_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

            $requests = explode(',',$_REQUEST['request_ids']);
            foreach($requests as $request_id) {

        $request_content = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/'".$request_id."_".$user_id."'?access_token=$app_token"), TRUE);
print_r($request_content);  //**nothing is printing**


$deleted = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$request_id?access_token=$app_token&method=delete");       





            }
```

I dono whats wrong on my coding im trying almost 7 days and I checked tutorial online most of those are old now the API have updated. I cant get the user_id even ... do I need to send my request OAuth Dialog??
    }

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
foreach($ids as $id) {
    //you will get your data here
    $data = $facebook - > api('/'.$user.'/apprequests?'.$access_token);

    //you will delete the request here
    $delete_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$id."_".$user."?".$access_token."&method=delete";
    $result = file_get_contents($delete_url);
}​
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi thax for your answer but im not geting the "$use_id" from $user_id= $facebook->getUser(); thats is my bigest problem

Comment: Also im not sending a OAuth Dialog for request!! im trying but I cudnt... how to send OAuth Dialog with multiple user requst?

Comment: are you prompting the user for multiple friend select ?

Comment: yes but I dont care if u can give a solution for single friend select

Comment: im sorry looks like i asked the wrong question, what did you mean by *sending a OAuth Dialog for request* ?

Comment: Do I need to send a Authentication within request?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas/